# What's the meaning of "Old Hob"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Murtogg: What we doin' 'ere?

Mullroy: The pirates come out, unprepared and unawares. We catch 'em in a crossfire... *send 'em down to see Old Hob*.

resource: "Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl" 105:51 out of 142:14

quotes: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0325980/quotes/?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old Hob is an informal term for Satan. (In English folklore a hob is a spirit.) The speaker means that the pirates will be killed by the gunfire. He presumes that they, being evil men, will go to Hell where Satan is supposed to preside.

Comment: Also [***Old Scratch***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Scratch) and [***Old Nick***](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/old-nick#:~:text=noun%20Informal.,the%20devil%3B%20Satan.), and probably others. All pretty "antiquated" today, though.